# encrypted integrations

Tags: integration, webservices

I'm making integration with another system. We have provided for incoming and outgoing synchronous calls. However, the client requested that the messages exchanged between the systems are encrypted. Is it possible to implement such policies? how? I found references to Shield Platform Encryption but it seems to be about the stored data and not the exchange.
Is it possible to expose a single WS to receive only part of the encrypted data and not in all the calls?

Comment: Shield Platform encryption is all about encrypting the data _at rest_ - meaning, protecting the data should it be hacked out of the SFDC servers

Comment: I need to encrypt and descript the messages exchanged not the data at rest

Answer (score 4):

Message exchanges *should* absolutely all go over HTTPS connections, which would mean that they're already encrypted in transit. (Integrated data should never be sent over HTTP).

If there's an expectation that the data be encrypted before transmission over an HTTPS channel, that's another layer, and Apex does have a `Crypto` class that can provide encryption support.

Encryption isn't something you just throw in and forget about, though. Design of secure encryption channels is *hard*, so getting a very clear specification of the requirements and threat model is critical. But likely the client just means that the communication channel should be encrypted, meaning HTTPS.

Comment: how can i see if the WS exposed accepts http or https ?

Comment: Does the endpoint you're calling start with `https://`?

Comment: is a WS inbound, I have generated the wsdl to provide it to the other systems and I see
 - targetNamespace,
 - xmlns: xsd,
 - xmlns,
 - xmlns: soap
with http, while at the end there is the tag
 - soap: address location
with https

Comment: None of the XML namespace stuff matters. Only the endpoint URL. What is your outside API consumer connecting to?

Comment: we decided to encrypt the value of the xml tag. Are there any problems with the data types, date, int and double?

Comment: Comments aren't for lengthy discussions, and I don't really know what that means. If you implement this and have more issues please ask another question and be very specific. You are keeping everyone guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two way SSL to exchange safe and secure information between the 2 systems.

Check this [link:](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Making_Authenticated_Web_Service_Callouts_Using_Two-Way_SSL)